# Fetch last modified object from AWS S3 CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to copy the latest file based on Last Modified from AWS S3 `Folder_Test1` folder to a `Folder_Test2` folder in the same bucket and using exclude and include in the copy command.

Folder_Test1:

```
Name                               Last Modified
T1_abc_june21.csv                  June 21,2020 9:27:03 AM GMT-0700
T1_abc_june21.csv                  June 21,2020 7:40:15 PM GMT-0700
T1_abc_june21.csv                  June 21,2020 9:20:32 PM GMT-0700
T1_abc_june25.csv                  June 25,2020 10:23:30 PM GMT-0700
T2_abc_june29.csv                  June 29,2020 6:15:12 AM GMT-0700
T2_abc_june29.csv                  June 29,2020 5:12:15 PM GMT-0700 (Fetch this object)
T1_abc_def_june21.csv              June 21,2020 6:13:15 PM GMT-0700
T2_abc_def_june25.csv              June 25,2020 5:33:10 AM GMT-0700
T3_abc_def_june25.csv              June 25,2020 9:31:15 PM GMT-0700 (Fetch this object)
```

I have to filter the file name having only the latest file of `abc` and exclude the copy files:

I tried:
Step 1 Copy `abc` files from Folder_Test1 to Folder_Test2:

```
aws s3 cp  s3://$bucket/Folder_Test1/ s3://$bucket/Folder_Test2/ --recursive --exclude "*abc_def*"
```

Step 2 It will Fetche latest `abc` file from Folder_Test2:

```
aws s3 ls  s3://$bucket/Folder_Test2/ --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

How can I copy the latest file from Folder_Test2 to Folder_Test3? or How can I remove all other files except the latest file from Folder_Test2?

Comment: You won't be able to get this directly out of the API, you will need local order/filter logic.

Answer (score 2):

How many files are you scanning?

If it's 100,000 or more, you might want to use something faster than aws-cli. **S3P** uses a parallel listing algorithm to accelerate S3 bucket listing by more than **10x**.

All you need to install is [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). Then run s3p with:

```
npx s3p map \
  --bucket  my-bucket \
  --prefix  Folder_Test1/ \
  --reduce  "js:(a, b) => a.LastModified > b.LastModified ? a : b" \
  --finally "js:({Key}) => Key"
```

That will output the key of the most recently modified file in `Folder_Test1/`.

More info:

- Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3p
- Github: https://github.com/generalui/s3p

Disclaimer: I wrote S3P for working with very large buckets.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work but it requires some shell related code and `jq`.  In a Linux environment I was able to do something like:

```
aws s3 cp s3://$bucket/`aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $bucket --prefix Folder_Test1/ | jq -r '.[] | sort_by(.LastModified)[-1].Key'` $bucket/Folder_Test2/
```

What does this do?  The first part finds the most recent file that starts with "Folder_Test1/" in this example:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $bucketsource --prefix Folder_Test1/ | jq -r '.[] | sort_by(.LastModified)[-1].Key'
```

Thew we pipe this output to `jq` to let it sort by the LastModified field and get the Key of that item.  Note that this is using `s3api` so that we can get the raw JSON to read.

Once we have that we use that output as input to the `cp` command.

This was tested with V2 of the AWS CLI (2.0.30) on an Ubuntu system.  The `jq` command was already installed.

Answer (score 1):

This command will list the 'latest' object for a given prefix:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket MY-BUCKET --prefix foo/ --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text
```

You could combine it with a copy command:

```
key=$(aws s3api list-objects --bucket SOURCE-BUCKET --prefix foo/ --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text)
aws s3 cp s3://SOURCE-BUCKET/$key s3://DEST-BUCKET/
```

The `--query` parameter is *very* powerful. See: [JMESPath Tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)

However, the `list-objects` command cannot be combined with `--include`/`--exclude`.

Frankly, it would probably be easier to write a small Python script to accomplish your goal.