# AWS CLI Command to list latest 7 ami' s and there snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, snapshot, amazon-ami

I need a cli command to list 7 latest ami's and there snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Fetch last modified object from AWS S3 CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63625126/174777), you should be able to limit the result set with:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --query 'sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[-7:].ImageId' --output text
```

You should be able to list the associated snapshots with something like this (but I didn't test it):

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --query 'sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[-7:].[ImageId, BlockDeviceMappings.Ebs.SnapshotId]' --output text
```

That should give you an idea of how to access the fields in the result set. Use the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html) to identify the desired fields.

Comment: i am not able to get output for above command which you provide

Comment: Windows can be a bit picky with quotation marks. Try double-quotes?

Comment: yes i tried that also but still i am having issues

Comment: C:\Users\shubham.s>aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --query "sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[-7:].[ImageId, BlockDeviceMappings.Ebs.SnapshotId]" --output text

An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeImages operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials

Comment: That indicates an error with you using the AWS CLI (regardless of the actual commands). For example, you can just run `aws ec2 describe-images --owners self` or `aws s3 ls` and it will probably give the same error. This is saying that invalid credentials were provided to the AWS CLI. You can set the credentials by using `aws configure` and you can see the  credentials stored in `~/.aws/credentials` to figure out what is happening.

Comment: is any another way to list latest 7 amis and snapshot using cli commands?

Comment: in this common snapshot is not listed